# How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments

What is the "best" way to handle command-line arguments?

It seems like there are several answers on what the "best" way is and as a result I am stuck on how to handle something as simple as:

```
script.ps1 /n name /d domain
```

AND

```
script.ps1 /d domain /n name.
```

Is there a plugin that can handle this better? I know I am reinventing the wheel here.

Obviously what I have already isn't pretty and surely isn't the "best", but it works.. and it is UGLY.

```
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $args.count; $i++ ) {
    if ($args[ $i ] -eq "/n"){ $strName=$args[ $i+1 ]}
    if ($args[ $i ] -eq "-n"){ $strName=$args[ $i+1 ]}
    if ($args[ $i ] -eq "/d"){ $strDomain=$args[ $i+1 ]}
    if ($args[ $i ] -eq "-d"){ $strDomain=$args[ $i+1 ]}
}
Write-Host $strName
Write-Host $strDomain
```

Answer (score 1157, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel. Normal PowerShell scripts have parameters starting with `-`, like `script.ps1 -server http://devserver`

Then you handle them in a `param` section (note that this **must** begin at the first non-commented line in your script).

You can also assign default values to your params, read them from console if not available or stop script execution:

```
 param (
    [string]$server = "http://defaultserver",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$username,
    [string]$password = $( Read-Host "Input password, please" )
 )
```

Inside the script you can simply

```
write-output $server
```

since all parameters become variables available in script scope.

In this example, the `$server` gets a default value if the script is called without it, script stops if you omit the `-username` parameter and asks for terminal input if `-password` is omitted.

Update:
You might also want to pass a "flag" (a boolean true/false parameter) to a PowerShell script. For instance, your script may accept a "force" where the script runs in a more careful mode when force is not used.

The keyword for that is `[switch]` parameter type:

```
 param (
    [string]$server = "http://defaultserver",
    [string]$password = $( Read-Host "Input password, please" ),
    [switch]$force = $false
 )
```

Inside the script then you would work with it like this:

```
if ($force) {
  //deletes a file or does something "bad"
}
```

Now, when calling the script you'd set the switch/flag parameter like this:

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -server "http://otherserver" -force
```

If you explicitly want to state that the flag is not set, there is a special syntax for that

```
.\yourscript.ps1 -server "http://otherserver" -force:$false
```

Links to relevant Microsoft documentation (for PowerShell 5.0; tho versions 3.0 and 4.0 are also available at the links):

- [about_Scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx)
- [about_Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx)
- [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

Comment: Indeed one of PowerShell's big advantages is that it provides a standard parameter parsing infrastucture that is easy to use.

Comment: @naivists, from PowerShell 2.0 instead of `[string]$username = $(throw "-username is required.")` there is syntax for mandatory parameters: `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$username`.
Here is more info about difference between these techniques: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/22/use-powershell-to-make-mandatory-parameters.aspx

Comment: Be wary of the bug when an arg is not supplied; powershell will just grab any extra text from the command line:
.\yourscript.ps1 -server "http://serv" -password "mypass" typo     
This will magically assign 'typo' to $username.

Comment: This is great! Could you make this a documentation? One question though: How to handle parameters with no `-option` tag?

Comment: Using a param block seems to have other unintended consequences though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940819/import-pssession-fails-in-script-works-in-shell

Comment: @sheamus: that is not a bug! Powershell will process and assign the arguments in the order they're given, unless overridden by using the proper parameter name, e.g., if your param block lists: $user $pass $server, and you execute yourscript.ps1 a b c, a will be set into $user, b into $pass and c into $server, UNLESS you specifically assign them!
So, if you say: yourscript.ps1 -pass a b c, $pass will be set to a, and the remaining (unnamed) parameters will be used to fill in the missing ones, in the order listed in the parameter block, so $user = b, $server = c.

Comment: The better way to do username and password is to use the `Credential` type, which will take care of hiding the password during typing and storing it as a `SecureString`. (I'm not totally sold on the value of `SecureString`, but at least it lowers the risk of it getting accidentally printed in the output.)

Comment: Great. But how to check if there are parameters given at all? In order to print a usage message for example.

Comment: @Scrontch, see this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643616/239599

Comment: Wow, you couldn't of just made an example file?

Comment: @sheamus one way to avoid the "typo" scenario is to explicitly deny positional binding, this can be done per parameter or globally. just add [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)] to the top of your cmdlet.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377616/1705829) is a nice example for positional arguments which goes more along the linux path.

Comment: @Timo awesome link, thanks, just what I needed! `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$True, Position=0)]` is the magic that prevents optional named parameters from consuming positional parameters.

Comment: Being a novice PowerShell programmer, I struggled for a good while with the error *The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file*.  The solution turned out to be simple: [I can use this function only as the first non-commented line of code in my script!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1315158/5025060)

Comment: Doesn't work. No value is passed only default is used

Comment: It seems to be `-force $false` hinted by https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592684/21294350 tested on pwsh `5.1.22621.2506`.