# How can I pass an argument to a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, command-line, automation, parameter-passing, itunes

There's a PowerShell script named `itunesForward.ps1` that makes iTunes fast forward 30 seconds:

```
$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application

if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
  $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + 30
}
```

It is executed with a prompt line command:

```
powershell.exe itunesForward.ps1
```

Is it possible to pass an argument from the command line and have it applied in the script instead of the hardcoded 30 seconds value?

Answer (score 795, accepted):

Tested as working:

```
#Must be the first statement in your script (not counting comments)
param([Int32]$step=30) 

$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application

if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
  $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + $step
}
```

Call it with

```
powershell.exe -file itunesForward.ps1 -step 15
```

Multiple parameters syntax (comments are optional, but allowed):

```
<#
    Script description.

    Some notes.
#>
param (
    # height of largest column without top bar
    [int]$h = 4000,
    
    # name of the output image
    [string]$image = 'out.png'
)
```

And some example for [advanced parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1), e.g. *Mandatory*:

```
<#
    Script description.

    Some notes.
#>
param (
    # height of largest column without top bar
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [int]$h,
    
    # name of the output image
    [string]$image = 'out.png'
)

Write-Host "$image $h"
```

A default value will not work with a mandatory parameter. You can omit the `=$true` for advanced parameters of type boolean `[Parameter(Mandatory)]`.

Comment: I think this way is more readable while executing the ps1 file. thanks

Comment: what if the parameter is a string?  What is the syntax? would it be something like -step '15' or -step "15"

Comment: @Andrew First of all you have to change the type of the parameter to `[string]`. If you then want to pass a string as parameter you can use either `'` or `"`. If there is no space (or quotes) inside the string you can even omit the quotes.

Comment: Thanks @OcasoProtal, yes I figured out single quotes were my friend.

Comment: FYI, to use multiple params, use this syntax: `param([string]$env,[string]$s3BucketName)`

Comment: It is missing "-file". It doesnt work for me until i added this. See the complete code: powershell.exe -file itunesForward.ps1 -step 15

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the hint. You are right: The `-file` is missing from the call. The call without might work with Powershell Version 1.0 but I can't test it. Updated the answer.

Comment: How can I pass an array of string with space?

Comment: I checked in windows 7: even `powershell.exe -file itunesForward.ps1  15` will work the same way.

Comment: @JoshPadnick But what will the call look like? Will it just be the list of variable names with values like so: powershell.exe -file itunesForward.ps1 -step 15 step1 20 step2 25 step3 'whatever string'? And I will list them by their name at the start of the code?

Comment: Why would the `Int32` type be capitalized but `string` isn't?

Comment: @starscream_disco_party Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c

Comment: @OcasoProtal thanks! Coming from Linux, damn near every design decision that MS makes makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: What about mandatory parameters? Where du you add the `Mandatory` keyword into the mix?

Answer (score 439):

You can use also the `$args` variable (that's like position parameters):

```
$step = $args[0]

$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application

if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
  $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + $step
}
```

Then it can be called like:

```
powershell.exe -file itunersforward.ps1 15
```

Comment: Found this easier than the accepted solution, PLUS you can directly use $args[0] anywhere in the script (no need to be first line). PS: Tip on passing strings as arguments: They must be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Both this and the accepted solution work, the main difference is that this reads parameters by position, while the accepted solution does it by name. When multiple parameters need to be passed, passing by name might be cleaner.

Comment: named params in accepted solution also auto populate get-help

Comment: This answer is getting so much attention, please check out the related one which is much more complete. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359618/pass-parameter-from-batch-file-to-the-powershell-script/6362404#6362404

Answer (score 43):

**Call the script from a batch file (*.bat) or CMD**

***[PowerShell Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6.0)***

```
pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World"

pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "path-to-script/Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World"

pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 Hello -Param2 World"

pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 Hello World"

pwsh.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 -Param2 World Hello"
```

***PowerShell***

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "path-to-script/Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 Hello -Param2 World"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 Hello World"

powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./Script.ps1 -Param2 World Hello"
```

---

**Call from PowerShell**

***PowerShell Core or Windows PowerShell***

```
& path-to-script/Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World
& ./Script.ps1 -Param1 Hello -Param2 World
```

---

**Script.ps1 - Script Code**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [System.String]
    $Param1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [System.String]
    $Param2
)

Write-Host $Param1
Write-Host $Param2
```

Comment: Does the `Position=0` setting turn it into a positional parameter rather than a flag?

Comment: if you don't use the parameter names, you need to send correct values respecting the positions. Check the update for this answer.

Answer (score 9):

Let PowerShell analyze and decide the data type. It internally uses a 'Variant' for this.

And generally it does a good job...

```
param($x)
$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application
if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
    $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + $x
}
```

Or if you need to pass multiple parameters:

```
param($x1, $x2)
$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application
if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
    $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + $x1
    $iTunes.<AnyProperty>  = $x2
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
# ENTRY POINT MAIN()
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $site,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $application,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $dir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [String] $applicationPool
)

# Create Web IIS Application
function ValidateWebSite ([String] $webSiteName)
{
    $iisWebSite = Get-Website -Name $webSiteName
    if($Null -eq $iisWebSite)
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Error: Web Site Name: $($webSiteName) not exists."  -Category ObjectNotFound
    }
    else
    {
        return 1
    }
}

# Get full path from IIS WebSite
function GetWebSiteDir ([String] $webSiteName)
{
    $iisWebSite = Get-Website -Name $webSiteName
    if($Null -eq $iisWebSite)
    {
        Write-Error -Message "Error: Web Site Name: $($webSiteName) not exists."  -Category ObjectNotFound
    }
    else
    {
        return $iisWebSite.PhysicalPath
    }
}

# Create Directory
function CreateDirectory([string]$fullPath)
{
    $existEvaluation = Test-Path $fullPath -PathType Any
    if($existEvaluation -eq $false)
    {
        new-item $fullPath -itemtype directory
    }
    return 1
}

function CreateApplicationWeb
{
    Param(
        [String] $WebSite,
        [String] $WebSitePath,
        [String] $application,
        [String] $applicationPath,
        [String] $applicationPool
        )
    $fullDir = "$($WebSitePath)\$($applicationPath)"
    CreateDirectory($fullDir)
    New-WebApplication -Site $WebSite -Name $application -PhysicalPath $fullDir -ApplicationPool $applicationPool -Force
}

$fullWebSiteDir = GetWebSiteDir($Site)f($null -ne $fullWebSiteDir)
{
    CreateApplicationWeb -WebSite $Site -WebSitePath $fullWebSiteDir -application $application  -applicationPath $dir -applicationPool $applicationPool
}
```

Comment: It's works
.\create-application-pool.ps1 -site xx_8010 -application AppTest -dirtestDir -applicationPool TestAppPool

Answer (score 6):

Create a PowerShell script with the following code in the file.

```
param([string]$path)
Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'} | select name, target
```

This creates a script with a path parameter. It will list all symbolic links within the path provided as well as the specified target of the symbolic link.

Answer (score 4):

You can also define a variable directly in the PowerShell command line and then execute the script. The variable will be defined there, too. This helped me in a case where I couldn't modify a signed script.

Example:

```
 PS C:\temp> $stepsize = 30
 PS C:\temp> .\itunesForward.ps1
```

with iTunesForward.ps1 being

```
$iTunes = New-Object -ComObject iTunes.Application

if ($iTunes.playerstate -eq 1)
{
  $iTunes.PlayerPosition = $iTunes.PlayerPosition + $stepsize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my particular use-case, I wanted to access the arguments from the profile which ignored the `params`, and simply checked for the *existence* of an argument (essentially a switch).

I have a batch script which runs a ps1 file but with a profile. That `profile.ps1` outputs text when it loads. In some scripts, I want to disable the output of that text if I don't need it. For that, I created some simple switches such as the example below.

This is a very basic version, but you could extend it if you wished. Using the 'silent-running' mode an example then...

**Inside my batch script:**

```batch
C:\path\to\pwsh.exe -Command "%~dpn0.ps1" -QuietProfile
```

**PowerShell script (inside `profile.ps1`):**

```powershell
[Boolean]$global:QuietProfile = [Boolean]([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() -match "-QuietProfile")

if (-not $global:QuietProfile) {
  Write-Host "I am some text which should not appear when -QuietProfile is passed"
}
```

By default (if you just opened pwsh.exe) then the `$global:QuietProfile` value will be false and you will see the output as normal.

Obviously you *could* pass `-NoProfile` in your command to prevent the profile being loaded at all, but there may be circumstances where you want some useful functions to load but not everything.