# Pass parameter from a batch file to a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In my batch file, I call the PowerShell script like this:

```
powershell.exe "& "G:\Karan\PowerShell_Scripts\START_DEV.ps1"
```

Now, I want to pass a string parameter to `START_DEV.ps1`. Let's say the parameter is `w=Dev`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does the script expect named parameter or an anonymous one?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Let's say you would like to pass the string `Dev` as a parameter, from your batch file:

```
powershell -command "G:\Karan\PowerShell_Scripts\START_DEV.ps1 Dev"
```

put inside your powershell script head:

```
$w = $args[0]       # $w would be set to "Dev"
```

This if you want to use the built-in variable `$args`. Otherwise:

```
 powershell -command "G:\Karan\PowerShell_Scripts\START_DEV.ps1 -Environment \"Dev\""
```

and inside your powershell script head:

```
param([string]$Environment)
```

This if you want a named parameter.

You might also be interested in returning the error level:

```
powershell -command "G:\Karan\PowerShell_Scripts\START_DEV.ps1 Dev; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
```

The error level will be available inside the batch file as `%errorlevel%`.

Answer (score 28):

Assuming your script is something like the below snippet and named testargs.ps1

```
param ([string]$w)
Write-Output $w
```

You can call this at the commandline as:

```
PowerShell.Exe -File C:\scripts\testargs.ps1 "Test String"
```

This will print "Test String" (w/o quotes) at the console. "Test String" becomes the value of $w in the script.

Answer (score 18):

When a script is loaded, any parameters that are passed are automatically loaded into a special variables `$args`. You can reference that in your script without first declaring it.

As an example, create a file called `test.ps1` and simply have the variable `$args` on a line by itself. Invoking the script like this, generates the following output:

```
PowerShell.exe -File test.ps1 a b c "Easy as one, two, three"
a
b
c
Easy as one, two, three
```

As a general recommendation, when invoking a script by calling PowerShell directly I would suggest using the `-File` option rather than implicitly invoking it with the `&` - it can make the command line a bit cleaner, particularly if you need to deal with nested quotes.

Answer (score 10):

Add the parameter declaration at the top of ps1 file

#### test.ps1

```
param(
  # Our preferred encoding
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [ValidateSet("UTF8","Unicode","UTF7","ASCII","UTF32","BigEndianUnicode")]
  [string]$Encoding = "UTF8"
)

write ("Encoding : {0}" -f $Encoding)
```

#### Result

```
C:\temp> .\test.ps1 -Encoding ASCII
Encoding : ASCII
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer from @Emiliano is excellent. You can also pass named parameters like so:

```
powershell.exe -Command 'G:\Karan\PowerShell_Scripts\START_DEV.ps1' -NamedParam1 "SomeDataA" -NamedParam2 "SomeData2"
```

Note the parameters are outside the command call, and you'll use:

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [string]$NamedParam1,
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [string]$NamedParam2
```