# Batch file call powershell pass variable to smtp $message

Tags: variables, powershell, batch-file, smtp

I have a batch file that is menu driven.  Users answer two questions.  Based on their answers 2 variables are created and files are transferred.  After that, my batch file calls a powershell script to email me.  I need to find a way to put the 2 variables from the batch file into the $message = section of the powershell script.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the batch file calls the powershell script, why can't you just pass the variables as parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass parameter from batch file to the powershell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359618/pass-parameter-from-batch-file-to-the-powershell-script)

Comment: Could you please explain how?

Comment: Check out Empo's answer in the linked question in my previous comment.  It explains it better than I could.

Comment: I'm very new to powershell.  In batch file I have set test=home, set test2=away, so I need the $message= "this is your 5home% and you are %away%", but cannot grasp that parameter aspect that you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting environment variables, you can reference those in a PowerShell script spawned from the same cmd.exe environment like so:

```
$message = "this is your $env:test and you are $env:test2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much 'Keith Hill'.  You saved the day.  I really appreciate it.  I can't wait to learn more about PowerShell.