# PowerShell script working as File Explorer extension

Tags: powershell, registry

I have written a GUI app in PowerShell. It has one  parameter.

At the beginning of the script I have:

```
param (
    [string]$Path
)
```

Before the Form appears, I fill in a control with `$Path`:

```
$Form.Add_Load({
    $txtSourceFile.Text = $Path
})
```

When I run the script interactively in PowerShell it seems to be working as expected. The `txtSourceFile` control is filled in with the argument from the command line.

```
.\ghead.ps1 -Path C:\src\data\ghead.ps1
```

However, when I run this as a File Explorer extension, it does not appear to receive the argument from the command line. The registry setting for the command is:

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.EXE C:\\Users\\lit\\bin\\ghead.ps1 -Path %1
```

There is no error message. It simply does not fill in the `$txtSourceFile.Text` field. Am I missing something obvious? How can I get this to work?

The question suggested as a duplicate does not deal with running as a Windows File Explorer extension. I am already using the param() technique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass parameter from batch file to the powershell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359618/pass-parameter-from-batch-file-to-the-powershell-script)

Comment: Don't you have to wrap this in a function and call the function to pass the parameter that way? I may be wrong but that is how I would do it.

Comment: @nkasco - What would you suggest as the registry entry to run a function inside the .ps1 file?

Comment: What will be the value of path here, can you hard code the path in registry and try ?

Comment: Can you please share how can I make an explorer shell extension in powershell? Particularly how to create registry entries which regsvr32.exe does for native DLLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem was an extraneous character in the `Users` directory name which was not presented in the question. The OP probably needs new glasses glued to his face so that he can see better and not go without them.

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.EXE -Command C:\Users\pwatson\bin\ghead.ps1 -Path
```

The final registry entry turned out to be:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \\ASERVER\D$\Install\Utilities\ghead.ps1 -Path %1
```