# powershell.exe cmd line variables

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if is possible to call a variable for use in a PowerShell script using the command line.

For instance, I have a script that I would like to run tonight.  I want to run it at two times using a different input file (csv) each time.

Can I call...

```
powershell.exe -command {$input = <csv path>} -file <script path>
```

and discretely call a variable for use in the script from outside of the script?  Do I just need to make two copies of the script with the variable change included in the script itself?  Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell scripts can have parameters, just as functions can. That way you can have one script and just call it with different input file names. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script) for a similar question, [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) what more you can do with parameters and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) for more commandline options.

Script

```
Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [string] $FileName)

Write-Output "Script called with $FileName"
```

Call

```
powershell.exe -file Untitled2.ps1 Test3.csv
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I am new to powershell and had heard about parameters, but I never understood what they were for or how to use them.  Now at least I know what to look for help on.  Thanks for the assist, I will look at your links.

Comment: @Acerbity I would also suggest doing a `get-help about_function*` in powershell to see the various help topics available at your fingertips, and read through them when you get a chance. I found about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters very helpful myself.