# How to use a Jenkins variable in my Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have written a simple script via `PowerShell` to gather some files and zip them into one folder, lets call it `Script.ps1`. I want to make the script run every time Jenkins does a new build, however I also would like the name of the zip file to be the `BUILD_NUMBER`.

How can I create a variable in `PowerShell` that is Jenkins's current build number? As of the moment I am calling the `Script.ps1` in the execute shell section of configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add arguments to your `Script.ps1`. Just use `Param` at the top of the script:

```
Param( $BuildNumber ) #must be first statement in script
# your current script goes here
```

then you can call the script passing `BUILD_NUMBER` as argument from Jenkins. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script) for calling Powershell script with argument.

Comment: can become cumbersome when you need to use more than one environment variable in the script

Answer (score 73):

I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but I believe `BUILD_NUMBER` is an environment variable.

To access it in PowerShell, use `$env:BUILD_NUMBER`

E.g. If using 7-zip

```
7z.exe a "$env:BUILD_NUMBER.zip" C:\Build\Path
```

Comment: I just tried this in Jenkins and it worked wonderfully.  Thanx!

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why your solution is marked with the green checkmark.  This is the real solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Powershell Plugin, see [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin).

It allows you to enter PowerShell commands directly in a text box in Jenkins.

Then you can use the available environment variables (see docu of the plugin). The usage is a little cryptic:

```
(Get-Content ./Sources/SlmMachineControl/GUI/Project1.rc).replace("`"FileVersion`", `"1.0.0.0`"" ,"`"FileVersion`" `"2.3.$($env:BUILD_NUMBER).0`"") | Set-Content ./Sources/SlmMachineControl/GUI/Project1.rc
```

Also note the escaping of the double-quotes. Took me quite a while :)