# powershell multiple arguments in one variable

Tags: powershell

I want to have variable number of args go into one variable
`script.ps1 first -second a -third b`

what I want is to have "first -second a -third b" all be in one variable.

Is this possible without passing all the arguments as one string?

Comment: Considering you say you don't want a string, can you clarify what you are asking? Meaning are you trying to pass these and assign them to a single hash table object, assign them as [params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592531/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-powershell-script), pass them directly to a starting function (as arguments), or something else?

Comment: Are you looking for [`$args`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)? What is the purpose of this? Why can't you simply use optional parameters?

Comment: I want to have one script be called (kind of acting as a parent) and then based on the first parameter blindly pass the rest of the arguments to another script. So I want the "-params" too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`ValueFromRemainingArguments` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parameterattribute.valuefromremainingarguments(v=vs.85).aspx) in the `Parameter` attribute of your one variable

#### script.ps1

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
  [psobject[]]$InputObject
)

foreach($value in $InputObject)
{
  Write-Host $value
}
```

Now you can supply as many arguments as you want to:

```
PS C:\> .\script.ps1 many arguments can go here
many
arguments
can
go
here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to treat the first argument in the list as a subcommand and pass the rest of the arguments on to other functions/cmdlets I'd simply [split](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/02/05/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays/)'n'[splat](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) the [automatic variable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2007/02/05/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays/) `$args`, e.g. like this:

```
$subcommand, $params = $args

switch ($subcommand) {
  'foo'   { Do-Some @params }
  'bar'   { Do-Other @params }
  default { Write-Error "Unknown subcommand: $_" }
}
```