# Passing a variable to a powershell script via command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am new to powershell, and trying to teach myself the basics.  I need to write a ps script to parse a file, which has not been too difficult.

Now I want to change it to pass a variable to the script.  that variable will be the parsing string.  Now, the variable will always be 1 word, and not a set of words or multiple words.

This seems uber simple yet is posing a problem for me.  Here is my simple code:

```
$a = Read-Host
Write-Host $a
```

When I run the script from my command line the variable passing doesn't work:

```
.\test.ps1 hello
.\test.ps1 "hello"
.\test.ps1 -a "hello"
.\test.ps1 -a hello
.\test.ps1 -File "hello"
```

As you can see, I have tried many methos with no success, of the script taking the value an outputting it.

The script does run, and waits for me to type a value, and when I do, it echos that value.

I just want it to output my passed in value, what minuscule thing am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157554/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-powershell)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial on Powershell params:

[PowerShell ABC's - P is for Parameters](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/powershell-abcs-p-is-for-parameters)

Basically, you should use a `param` statement on the **first line** of the script

`param([type]$p1 = , [type]$p2 = , ...)`

or use the $args built-in variable, which is auto-populated with all of the args.

Comment: @MichaelHedgpeth: It looks like it was a temporary problem; it's back up now. I don't know of a more permanent link for the article.

Comment: Personally the $args parameter is easier. :)

Comment: The link is broken again :-(

Comment: @MichaëlPolla: I wish they would stop moving the article! I fixed the link again.

Answer (score 79):

Make this in your test.ps1, at the first line

```
param(
[string]$a
)

Write-Host $a
```

Then you can call it with

```
./Test.ps1 "Here is your text"
```

Found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/magazine/jj554301.aspx) ([English](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/jj554301(v=msdn.10)))

Comment: Id rather call it with ./Test.ps1 -a="Here is your text" but its printing $a like this: -a=Here is your string

Comment: @ozzy432836 I too prefer that syntax, but it is not built into powershell. Without a space PS sees it as a single unnamed argument. You can certainly implement your own argument parsing, but you might consider that it will not be what anyone else expects. Powershell's built-in functionality allows for named and unnamed (aka positional) arguments, mandatory and optional arguments with default values and automatically generates help. That is a lot to throw away because you (& I) prefer an '=' over a space. I wasted my time re-inventing this wheel in C# Few of my users could care.

Comment: Writing it in first line is important as it gives error if param is not in first line.

Answer (score 13):

Declare the parameter in test.ps1:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$input_dir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$output_dir,
    [switch]$force = $false
)
```

Run the script from Run OR Windows Task Scheduler:

```
powershell.exe -command "& C:\FTP_DATA\test.ps1 -input_dir C:\FTP_DATA\IN -output_dir C:\FTP_DATA\OUT"
```

or,

```
powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\FTP DATA\test.ps1' -input_dir 'C:\FTP DATA\IN' -output_dir 'C:\FTP DATA\OUT'"
```

Answer (score 7):

Passed parameter like below,

```
Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true,
   HelpMessage="Enter name and key values")]
   $Name,
   $Key)
```

> .\script_name.ps1 -Name **name** -Key **key**

Comment: How does the help message come in?

Comment: @not2qubit Actually help text will be useful if user doesn't know how to execute. For getting that help text you have to type !? without passing any input.

Answer (score 3):

Using param to name the parameters allows you to ignore the order of the parameters:

ParamEx.ps1

```
# Show how to handle command line parameters in Windows PowerShell
param(
  [string]$FileName,
  [string]$Bogus
)
write-output 'This is param FileName:'+$FileName
write-output 'This is param Bogus:'+$Bogus
```

ParaEx.bat

```
rem Notice that named params mean the order of params can be ignored
powershell -File .\ParamEx.ps1 -Bogus FooBar -FileName "c:\windows\notepad.exe"
```