# Replacing content of file via regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to first find the file name (e.g XXX.txt) (which can be anything, BBB is just an example) stored in the .ps1 file and if found replace that by a value entered in the console. then I will update with a new one such as test.txt instead of xxx.txt

```
$DName = read-host -prompt "Please Enter File Name"

(Get-Content "C:\run.ps1") | 
Foreach-Object { $content = $_ -replace "$????","$DName" } | 
Set-Content "C:\run.ps1"
```

run.ps1 file:

```
$line = ''
Get-Content C:\bulk\XXX.txt | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'TEMP' |
        ForEach-Object {
        #blah blah
        }
```

Comment: Frame challenge: don't hard-code the file name. Pass it [as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16426688/503046) instead.

Comment: I am really not following you. This all seems very convoluted. You prompt the user for some random DBName, which you then try and look for in the results via a read call. You have no error checking for when that DBName does not exist. What is in $old, because you are not showing it. What is $line for? You are not using it anywhere. As for the -Pattern match. What are you trying to do with that?  What is in Clients.txt and xxx.txt?  Please up date your post.

Comment: @postanote  sorry you are right. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$_ -replace "(Get-Content\s+(['`"]?)C:\\bulk\\).*?(\.txt\2)", ('${1}' + $DName.replace('$','$$') + '$3')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DLSzNE/2)

**Details**

- `` (Get-Content\s+(['`"]?)C:\\bulk\\) ``  - Group 1:

  - `Get-Content\s+` - `Get-Content` and then 1+ whitespaces
  - `(.*?)` - Group 2: a `'`, `"` or empty string
  - `C:\\bulk\\` - `C:\bulk\` substring
- `.*?` - 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(\.txt\2)` - Group 2: `.txt` and the text captured in Group 2.

The replacement is the result of concatenating:

- `${1}` - Group 1 value (the braces are a must if `BBB` may actually start with a digit)
- `$DName.replace('$','$$')` - the new file name with doubled `$` chars (as these are special in .NET replacement patterns)
- `$3` - Group 3 value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But  I have written only as example BBB. So this is dynamic. which can be anything, BBB is just an example.

Comment: @Arbelac I thought it was the simplest part (it is almost not related to regex), added to the answer.

Comment: @Arbelac I used the same variable names, does it work now?

Comment: I have been testing it. I will provide feedback to you