# How to require command-line arguments (not parameters) in the PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, powershell-1.0

Different from: [How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157554/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-powershell)

What's the best way to handle an **unnamed** command-line argument in a powershell script?

For example, I have a powershell script that I would like to run as

```
.\test.ps1 L3
```

and have an error if L3 is not supplied.  I don't want to have to run it as:

```
.\test.ps1 -lab L3
```

My current script:

```
$args[0]
```

does not cause an error if the argument is omtted.

This looks promising, haven't tried it yet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx
*** Edit: ***
The promising link is useful -- I used it to form all my examples

Comment: Why don't you want named arguments (parameters)? They make for much more readable code, and if you set up your parameters properly I think you can leave them unnamed when you pass them in, as long as you do it in the right order.

Comment: Named arguments are great.  But this script ALWAYS requires this argument and it will save three-four keystrokes every time I use it.

Comment: If it's the only argument, you can make it named and pass it in un-named and PowerShell will handle it just fine. Don't write for *your convenience* - write to make your script understandable for the next person who has to use it and isn't you.

Comment: This argument is only provided at the command-line, not in another script.  I agree that in scripts, named parameters are a good thing.

Comment: My point remains. Even at the command line, **write for the understanding of the next person, not for your convenience**. Named parameters are almost always a good thing, regardless - when someone has to modify this script to add another parameter, they'll want them named. It costs you nothing to make it named now, just do it.

Comment: This seems like a potentially contentious point.  Perhaps it's just my bash background, but I find unnamed parameters for one or two essential arguments to be perfectly readable in many cases. Perhaps this is an exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71801/discussion-between-josiah-yoder-and-alroc).

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick:

```
Param
  (
     [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
     [String]
     $LabNumber
  ) 

$LabNumber
```

This second option is interesting, but I prefer the Mandatory=$true above, because it will actually prompt you to enter it if you forget it.

```
Param
  (
     [parameter(Position=0)]
     [String]
     $LabNumber=$(throw "LabNumber is required.  Usage Example: .\test.ps1 L3")
  ) 

$LabNumber
```

And, as @alroc prefers for all parameters, the second parameter must be named:

```
Param
  (
     [parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
     [String]
     $LabNumber,

     [alias("Submissions")] 
     [String]
     $LoginsFilename = "..\logins.txt"
  )
"LabNumber:"+$LabNumber
"LoginsFilename:"+$LoginsFilename
```