# Passing variables from chef to powershell

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I am using the powershell_script cookbook. The powershell script that I would like to use takes command line inputs. Is there a way to pass variables from chef and pass them into the powershell script?

```
input1 = "input1"
input2 = "input2"

powershell_script 'example' do
  code "...\example.ps1"
end
```

So if my example.ps1 took input1 and input2 as command line arguments how would I pass them into:

`code "...\example.ps1"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157554/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `code` property on the `powershell_script` resource takes the literal PowerShell code you want to run, not a path to it. Regardless, you would handle it via string interpolation. For example:

```
execute "C:/path/to/example.ps1 #{node['foo']} #{node['bar']}"
```