# chef parameterized powershell

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I have PowerShell script. I want to call from chef. How can we call it from chef?

```
param(
  [string] $dataSource  
)
function Invoke-SQL {
  $dataSource | out-file D:\Parameter.txt
}

Invoke-SQL -dataSource $dataSource
```

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/resource_powershell_script.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36560150/361842

Comment: Thanks,Now it woks for me with code "C:/path/to/example.ps1 #{node['foo']} #{node['bar']}"