# How to check if a PowerShell optional argument was set by caller

Tags: powershell

I have a script which takes these arguments:

```
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [Int]$startRevision,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [Int]$endRevision,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
    [Int]$stepSize = 10,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String]$applicationToBuild
)
```

Since the last argument is optional, I would like to know if the argument is set. Is there any way to do this?

A default is not ok, since I don't want to use the variable if it is not set. I could use a default which is a "ThisIsNotSet" and check if the value is equal to this string, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**The automatic [`$PSBoundParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) variable** is a hashtable-like object available inside functions whose **`.Keys` property** contains the **names of all parameters to which arguments were explicitly passed** on invocation.<sup>[1]</sup>

Thus, in your case, `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('applicationToBuild')` tells you whether an argument was passed to `-applicationToBuild` (expression evaluates to `$True`) or not (`$False`).

---

Note: The advantage of this approach is that it is **unambiguous**, whereas testing for the parameter-variable type's default value, as in [trbox' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643473/45375), doesn't allow you to distinguish between *not passing* an argument and *explicitly passing the type's default value* (the empty string, in this case).

---

<sup>[1] Note that parameters bound *implicitly* via *default values* are *not* included; including the latter would be helpful when passing arguments through to another function, as discussed in [GitHub issue #3285](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

`$applicationToBuild` is an empty string if nothing is passed in to the script, since the type of the parameter is `[String]`.
 So if the parameter "is not set", `$applicationToBuild.Length` will be `0`.

You can use that when deciding whether the parameter should be used or not.

Comment: Unless you need to distinguish between the case of "not passed" VS "passed empty".

Comment: You’re right. In any case, mklement0’s solution is much better and is the one that should be used.