# Detect empty variable in Powershell parameter list or avoid using next string input

Tags: windows, powershell, variables, ps1

I'm trying to read out parameters out of a ps1-file with a Powershell script. (Run with powershell *inputfile.ps1* which is calling *evaluation.ps1*) The input file looks like this:

```
$a=5
$b=""
$c=
$d=555
```

Unfortunately it's seems impossible to detect the not existing variable 'c' with the conventional methods e.g., `$null`, `-eq ""`,`''`, `-is [string]` or similar methods. This ends up that my Powershell script automatically uses the next value from variable 'd'. So in the end I get this information:

```
echo "$a"
5
echo "$b"

echo "$c"
555
echo "$d"
555
```

Is there any possibility to avoid using the value from next line or somehow detect a missing input? Unfortunately the ps1-input file should not be touched (I know when using an empty string as input like b="", all the above mentioned methods work fine).

Thanks for any help in advance.

I guess I tried all hints out of stackoverflow already here but since it's not a string but an empty input nothing works.

Comment: `$c=` is not valid code. Please share the actual parameter assignment and/or script invocation you doing or create a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to check if a PowerShell optional argument was set by caller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643616/1701026)?

Comment: @iRon, `$c=` automatically continues on the next line, so the whole statement - which _is_ valid - is `$c=$d=555`

Answer (score 1):

To spell it out: Your `.ps1` script is *malformed with respect to your intent*, given that:

```bash
$c=
$d=555
```

despite the newline, is the same as `$c=$d=555`, which by design assigns `555` to *both* `$c` and `$d`.

You have two basic options if you want `$c` to be `$null` instead:

- (a) *Preprocess* your file to replace a missing value after `=` with `$null` and then, instead of [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) it, execute the preprocessed content via [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-Expression)

  - **Note**: Given that dot-sourcing and `Invoke-Expression` (which is [generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)) allow execution of arbitrary code, be sure that you fully control or implicitly trust the script's content.
- (b) Parse your file *manually*, line by line, and define the variables one by one, using [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Set-Variable).

###### Implementation of (a)

Note:

- The assumption is that any line that ends in `=` is also a simple assignment statement, as shown in your question.
- The [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation matches a line-ending `=` (optionally followed by whitespace only) and replaces it with verbatim `=$null`. This means that such variables will still be *defined*, but with value `$null`.

  - For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) (`(?m)=\s*$`) and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/wOjtRg/1).

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw yourScript.ps1) -replace '(?m)=\s*$', '=$null' |
  Invoke-Expression
```

---

###### Implementation of (b)

Note:

- The assumption is that your script file contains *only* assignment statements as shown in your question.
- The assignment values must be *literal* values, not ones that require interpretation by PowerShell.
- On the plus side, this approach prevents execution of arbitrary code.

```bash
Get-Content yourScript.ps1 |
  ForEach-Object {
    $name, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
    if ($value -eq '') { $value = $null }
    else               { $value = $value.Trim('"') }
    Set-Variable -Name $name.TrimStart('$') -Value $value
  }
```