# How to tell if a variable was passed in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, if-statement, null

```
function turtlesong {
    param(
        [string]$time,
        [string]$link,
        [string]$number
    )
    # create exception for when variables are not passed
    if ($time -eq $null -or $link -eq $null -or $number -eq $null) {
        return "variables that need to be passed: -time, -link, -number"
    }

    if (Test-Path "C:\Users\aster\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4" -eq $false) {
        C:\Users\###\.stacher/youtube-dl --embed-metadata --no-check-certificate --ffmpeg-location C:\Windows\ --download-sections "*$time" -o "C:\Users\###\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4" $link 
        
        $choice = Read-Host "Use ffmpeg and convert to audio? (y/n)"
        if ($choice -eq "y") {
            ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\###\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4" -vn -c:a copy "C:\Users\###\turtlesongs\audio\song.$number.m4a"
        } else {
            write-host "Not converting to audio."
        }
    } else {
        write-host "Song already downloaded, incrementing number by 1."
        $number = $number + 1
        turtlesong -time $time -link $link -number $number
    }
}
```

At first I had it so the null was checked after the three or's, copilot said to add a check for each, but neither works, and it continues right past.

Comment: Closely related: [How to check if a PowerShell optional argument was set by caller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48643250/45375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison fails to exit your function early, because your parameters are typed as `string`, when no arguments are passed to your function, then these parameters become an [empty string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty) and an empty string is not `null`:

```bash
'' -eq $null -or '' -eq $null -or '' -eq $null # is false
```

However, you could use [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2) here, negating an empty string becomes `true` in PowerShell so, this condition would work:

```bash
-not '' -or -not '' -or -not '' # is true
```

But, taking a step back, there is a much better approach to avoid all this trouble, make your parameters [`Mandatory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.4#mandatory-argument):

```bash
function turtlesong {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $time,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $link,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $number
    )

    if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Users\aster\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4")) {
        $choice = Read-Host 'Use ffmpeg and convert to audio? (y/n)'
        if ($choice -eq 'y') {
            ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\###\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4" -vn -c:a copy "C:\Users\###\turtlesongs\audio\song.$number.m4a"
            return
        }

        Write-Host 'Not converting to audio.'
        return
    }

    Write-Host 'Song already downloaded, incrementing number by 1.'
    $number = $number + 1
    turtlesong -time $time -link $link -number $number
}
```

There is also an extra issue here:

```bash
if (Test-Path "C:\Users\aster\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4" -eq $false) {
```

You must use [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) to wrap the `Test-Path` expression, otherwise PowerShell thinks that `-eq $false` are actually arguments to `Test-Path` (you can also use `-not` here instead of `-eq $false`):

```bash
if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Users\aster\turtlesongs\song.$number.mp4")) {
```

Comment: also: is Best Practice™ to put the static value on the left of the comparisons, ex: `if ($null -eq (Whatever -Function)) { <#MAGIC#>}`, because the left argument sets the Type for the comparison. While this is mostly irrelevant for booleans results, especially because you can simply use them straight in the `if()`, it can save you pain from messy automatic casting\conversion