# How do I translate a set of powershell commands into a script that I can run when I want?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a set of commands I can use in azure powershell.  The commands create a resource group, app service, etc.  I want to bundle them up so that I can just type one command into a terminal and run all of the deployment in one go.

```
# Ask user for work item id
$workItemId = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Work Item ID"

# Set Variables
$appdirectory="C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Timesheet App\Discover\Client\build"
$webappname="discoverTest$workItemId"
$location="West Europe"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzResourceGroup -Name discoverTest$workItemId -Location $location

# Create an App Service plan in `Free` tier.
New-AzAppServicePlan -Name $webappname -Location $location `
-ResourceGroupName discoverTest$workItemId -Tier Free

# Create a web app.
New-AzWebApp -Name $webappname -Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName discoverTest$workItemId

# Get publishing profile for the web app
$xml = [xml](Get-AzWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName discoverTest$workItemId `
-OutputFile null)

# Extract connection information from publishing profile
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

# Upload files recursively 
Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse #Removed IsContainer condition
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')  
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")

    if($file.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
        $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
        $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true

        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

        $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
        $response.StatusDescription
        continue
    }

    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri + " from "+ $file.FullName

    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()



$workItemId = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Work Item ID"
Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name "discoverTest$workItemId" -Force

# print variable
Write-Host $variable
```

I want to be able to run a single command and have the full deployment process executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to realize your needs, as below.

1. Extract all parameters you used in these PowerShell command lines as the arguments for a PowerShell Script `<your-script-name>.ps1` which includes all same commands as yours. Please refer to the existing SO thread [How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157554/how-to-handle-command-line-arguments-in-powershell) to know how to do. Then, you just need to run `<your-script-name>.ps1` with these arguments in a terminal which had pre-installed Azure PowerShell Module.
2. Follow the blog [`Four ways to package a non-GUI PowerShell script as an executable file`](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2019/06/27/three-ways-to-package-your-powershell-non-gui-script-file-to-an-executable-file/) to make an executable file with the current set of commands.

Normally, I think the first way is better and be recommended.