# Powershell Cmdlet with Mandatory Parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a simple powershell cmdlet that would have a few mandatory parameters. I've found the following code for doing so however, I cannot get it to execute:

```
function new-command() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
}

new-command
```

Returns the following error:

Missing closing ')' in expression." Line: 5 Char: 3 + [ <<<< string]$Name

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't duplicate that error with the posted script.

Comment: Yep. Throws an error if I don't include an argument after new-command, and quietly does nothing if I do.

Answer (score 10):

The explanation is that you are running this script in PowerShell V1.0 and these function attributes are supported in PowerShell V2.0. Look at `$host` variable for you PowerHhell version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
function new-command {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
}

new-command
```

You don't need parentheses after the function name.

Comment: His code works in PowerShell V2.0, but not in V1.0. In V1.0 the code gives exactly the error discribed

Answer (score 1):

In PS 2.0 mandatory parameters are controlled through the CmdLetBinding and Parameter attributes as shown in the other answers.

```
function new-command {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Name
    )
    $Name
}

new-command
```

In PS 1.0 there are not direct constructs for handling mandatory attributes but you can for example throw an error if a mandatory parameter hasn't been supplied. I often use the following construct.

```
function new-command {
    param($Name=$(throw "Mandatory parameter -Name not supplied."))
    $Name
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have the same error message even with Powershell v2.0 if Param(...) hasn't been declared at the beginning of the script (exclude comment lines).  Please refer to [powershell-2-0-param-keyword-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315140/powershell-2-0-param-keyword-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try below syntax and also kindly check whether have missed any *double quotes* or *bracket*s.

`Param([parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Path to file")] $path)`